# Link to a page then execute a Javascript request

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know if it is possible to link to a page using href and then calling a javascript function?

Ex:
href="http://www.mywebsite.com/Details.aspx?javascript:__doPostBack('INFO','')

How would I go about this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you trying to run the javascript on the new page?

Comment: Is the linked page also from your website, or just any other random page?

Comment: @ianpgall Yes. I am trying to run javascript on the new page.

Comment: @bfavaretto The linked page is to another website that I do not control

Comment: then it is not possible to run or call a javascript function, unless the new page accepts a GET parameter that will run a function call. if you have no control over the new page and it doesn't do this, you can't do it!

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot run javascript in another page like that. But you can prevent the default behavior of the click, load the page in an iframe, then run js there ([same origin policy](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy) may apply).

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to pass a variable to the page with a value, such as `somelink.com?navigation=method`

Then, on that page, GET the variable `navigation` and write a simple if statement, such as:

```
if ( navigation === "someMethod" ){
    theMethodToCall();
}
```

Comment: Looking at your answer, now I think that's what the OP is looking for, not what I thought when I answered. But he probably doesn't know how to read the GET parameter also...

Comment: @bfavaretto I was actually looking for something like what you stated. Is it really possible to load the page in an iframe and then automatically execute an OnLoad? That will actually solve my question.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? It probably doesn't require using an iframe.

Comment: @Dave I'm trying to execute some Javascript after loading the linked page all within one href link.

Ex: href=link.com/[javascript code to execute]

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it is possible to do it **exactly** like that. But how essential is it to pass javascript code through an href? 

You could achieve (I think) exactly what you are explaining with my solution.

Comment: @Dave What if I can't edit the second page? That is why I was thinking an iframe could work. Would that do the trick?